# Resolution of a Boolean function

Tags: boolean, algebra

i have to solve this simple boolean function :

f1 * f2 = (x1 + x2) * (!x1 + x3)

The solution is :
x1*x3 + !x1*x2

Anyone can make a step by step solution becouse after getting :

x1*x3 + x2*(!x1) + x2*x3

I don't know how to procede (i get stucked).
Thanks

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is a question about Boolean algebra, not programming. Try http://cs.stackexchange.com/ or http://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: @RaymondChen I agree in theory, but as programmers boolean algebra is kind of important. So I will answer it anyway.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about Boolean algebra instead of directly about programming.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(x1 + x2) * (!x1 + x3) = 
(x1*!x1) + (x1*x3) + (x2*!x1) + (x2*x3) = 
(x1*x3) + (x2*!x1) + (x2*x3)
```

Then, `(x2*x3)` is redundant, since if the expression is true, either `(x1*x3)` is true or `(x2*!x1)` is true. And necessarily, `x1 + !x1`. You can thus ignore `(x2*x3)` and you end up with:

```
(x1*x3) + (x2*!x1)
```